# What is the difference between self and yourself in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, visualworks, amber-smalltalk

In Smalltalk, there are two terms often found within a method body: `self` and `yourself`.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The reserved word `self` is a pseudo variable (you cannot assign to it) that refers to the current receiver of the method where it is used. On the other side `yourself` is a message you can send to any object to get that very same object.

The implementation of `yourself` is

```
yourself
    ^self
```

meaning that the message `yourself` will behave as I just explained.

The reason why `yourself` exists is to support message cascading, where you put it as the last message to make sure the resulting expression will answer with the receiver:

```
^receiver
   msg1;
   msg2;
   yourself
```

If `msg2` might answer with something different from the `receiver` you can append the `yourself` message to ignore that answer and return `receiver` instead. Of course you could have achieved the same result by writing:

```
receiver
   msg1;
   msg2.
^receiver
```

Because of the simplicity of these two examples, it might be hard to understand what the advantage would be. However, consider that `receiver` is not a variable but a complex expression, something like.

```
^(self msg: arg1 arg: arg2)
   msg1;
   msg2;
   yourself.
```

Without using `yourself` you would have to add a temporary to save the value of the receiver to achieve the same:

```
| answer |
answer := self msg: arg1 arg: arg2.
answer
   msg1;
   msg2.
^answer
```

which is a little bit more verbose.

To summarize, `self` is a reserved word that refers to the current receiver and `yourself` is just a regular method that is there just for convenience.

Answer (score 6):

`self` is a synonym for an object: specifically the receiver of the message that invoked the method. It is used within the body of a method.

`yourself` is a message that you can send to an object, that returns the receiver of the message.

`anObject yourself` returns `anObject`.

`yourself` is often used at the end of a *message cascade* within a method body.

When you want the return value from the method to be the receiver, but the final message in the cascade returns something else, you could write either:

```
self aMessageReturningTheReceiver;
      aMessageReturningTheArgument: anArgument .
^self
```

or

```
self aMessageReturningTheReceiver;
      aMessageReturningTheArgument: anArgument;
      yourself
```